# friendly URL and ? tag

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I have the following structure:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ page.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]
```

and I can get to my page named "talk" with the urls:

```
site.com/page/talk
site.com/page/talk/
```

thats okay, but I want to dinamically add some options and I dont want to create more rewrite rules, I wanted to use the normal GET in the same link, like:

```
site.com/page/talk/?fontsize=15
```

How can i I do that?

also, is there any way to use something like this below?

```
RewriteRule ^pages/order-([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages.php?order=$1 [NC,L]
```

I've tried but couldn't do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forgot about this old question, nowdays when i need to have ? arguments, i use QSA flag.

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9-]+)(/?)$ page.php?pagename=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I simplified two rules to one by using (/?), that means it can have the / and the end, and the QSA flag appends the ? values to the end, like the example below:

```
page/home?debug=true
```

resulting:

```
page.php?pagename=$1&debug=true
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can just move the original query string to merge with the new query string. Unfortunately, because of the way said query strings are laid out, this has to be done in a seperate rule. In other news, your regular expression seems a bit malformed. Here's the new ones:

```
RewriteRule ^page(?:/([a-z0-9\-]+))?/?$ page.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page(?:/([a-z0-9\-]+))?/?\?(.*)$ page.php?pagename=$1&$2 [NC,L]
```

See how the first two got merged into one?

Comment: I can see that it merged, but i tested with my Xampp and it doesn't work. Not Found The requested URL /page/pagenametwo/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: still The requested URL /revenda/page/pagename was not found on this server. '-'

Comment: It doesn't appear that's _supposed_ to match, though.

Comment: Why? The .htaccess file is under revenda folder